# $\{x:|f(x)|>5\}$ is the union of at most $2m$ intervals on each of which $f$ is monotone

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$. We use $f^{(m)}$ to denote the $m$-th derivative of $f$. Fix an integer $m\ge 1$. Prove that if $f^{(m)}(x)\ge 1$ for all $x$, then the set $\{x:|f(x)|>5\}$ is the union of at most $2m$ intervals on each of which $f$ is monotone.

I can prove this in the case $m=1$. Then perhaps I can use induction but I don't know how to proceed. Any method of proof is welcomed.